# String class in java

Tags: java

In java String is a class and it is imutable so we can not change its value.In following code it will concate other string without any error.So I want to ask that if it is immutable then why in this following code value of String is changed??

```
import java.util.*;

public class conc
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String a="Sheetal";
        a=a+"Ga";
        System.out.println("Result:"+a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's not a reference to the original `String` object?

Comment: `a = a + "Ga"` is actually creating an entirely "new" instance `String`.  Try printing the `hashcode` of `a` before and after the assignment ;).  Also try `String b = a + "Ga"` and print out both `a` and `b`...

Comment: You are correct , If you are not assigning with a new String :)

Comment: take some time reading about Strings and if you must ask a question, try researching existing questions in SO first, prior to asking such basic questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the code that you have shown, you have not changed the original `String` object.

Instead, you have created a new String object, which represents `a + "Ga"`, and then re-assigned it to the reference variable `a`.

Note that all variables in `Java` other than [primitive types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) are references.

Answer (score 6):

You are creating a new object by concatenating two strings, that is: You are not changing the object referenced by `a` but assigning to that reference the value referencing to a new `String` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String a="Sheetal";
        a=a+"Ga"; // now this is not the same object you are referring early
```

When you alter your `a` will create a new `String`.

Your original `String` is not change that's why we call `String` are `immutable` and new `String` will create in the heap.

In this moment there are 2 object in your heap. now `a` is referring new Object.

Comment: Where are your reason to downvote?. Is this not provide answer? who are the people downvote this??? mentally ill or any other issue

Comment: Now `stackOverFlow` become senseless.

Comment: It seems like those downvotes are caused by your english, sorry, but it's hard to understand what you mean :(

Comment: @krems ohh my English is that much bad? :(. BTW thank for your comment. Now I know at least a possible reason to downvote. See people please use to put a comment when you downvote. It will help all of us.

Comment: What moderator says about downvote-: `There's no requirement to give reasons for down-votes` nice

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Stackoverflow would be a lot better if a reason would be mandatory to down vote instead the -2 points penalization.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo yes. It is.